# Github pages with Jekyll : order navigation bar and title with minima?

Tags: github, markdown, jekyll

I create a static website with Github and Jekyll ( minima theme). I have two questions the configuration of my pages :

**First question :**

How Can I change the order of my navigation bar ?

For the moment, my navigation bar looks like :

[image: image_1]

I would like :

```
Homepage  skill CV cc
```

But I don't know how to do that...

**Second question :**

As you can see on the picture, I've created a file with the page layout :

```
---
layout: page 
title: skill 
permalink: /skill/
---
```

So this page appears in my navigation bar, but when I click on it, the title appears on the page :

[image: image_2]

Can you tell me how to not display this title ?

Maybe create a new layout ?

Thank you !

Comment: You are missing information on your current navigation bar.  We see the desired navigation bar, but without knowing what the navigation bar current looks like, it will be difficult to see what kind of code behavior change you are wanting.

Comment: Hello ! You don't see the picture below the " For the moment, my navigation bar looks like : " ?

Comment: Hello, I see the picture now. I am not sure why I could not see it in the past. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Response to Question 2:**

You can delete the three lines below from `page.html` [1].  I am assuming you will never want to use the original `layout: page` design provided by the minima theme.

```
  <header class="post-header">
    <h1 class="post-title">{{ page.title | escape }}</h1>
  </header>
```

[1] https://github.com/jekyll/minima/blob/437522fa8f5e48ba3815fd9893c525ee1e887030/_layouts/page.html#L6-L8